# Implications of adding extra "control" conditions to an ANOVA?

Tags: anova, interaction, sample-size, statistical-power

I'm planning a 2x3 ANOVA, all between subjects.  I'm expecting a weak main effect for A...a main effect for B where one condition is different than the other two...and then an interaction effect where the impact of A is stronger for two conditions of B.

A question has come up about whether to add a fourth condition of "B."  For the main effect of B, we would then be expecting that the one condition would be different than the other THREE...and then for an interaction effect, we would expect that the impact of A would be stronger for three conditions of B compared to the one.

My question is -- does adding this extra condition (which would be sort of an additional "control" condition) do anything to my statistical power of finding an effect for the overall ANOVA?  Assuming I add more participants, of course, to fill in the extra condition.

Comment: Will this change require $4/3$ as many subjects as before--perhaps 80 instead of 60? $(800 \,vs.\, 600?)$ If you put those additional subj's into the current design, what would be the increase in power? If you expanded the design, in what way might the results be more convincing? // If adding 1 add'l level to B is good, why not consider  2 or 3 or 4 add'l levels instead? // Designing an expt always involves many trade-offs; just trying to get you to focus more sharply on the one you propose here. Without more details of the nature of your expt, your intuition is likely to be better than ours.

Comment: @BruceET, these are great questions.  Adding the one level is in response to an advisor who is interested in making a particular comparison...I had planned to have 50 subjects per cell before and for the new cell was going to add the same.

Comment: Hard to argue with that. Supposing the present expt turned out pretty much as expected, can the two of you honestly say you'd be sorry you didn't add the extra level of B. If so, seems you should go ahead with the change. Wishing you success.